# Selecting the text contents in a particular <div> that has another <div> within it using Scrapy and Xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

EDIT: Solved! For those who encounter this in their learning; The answer is bellow, nicely explained and provided by Paul.

This is my first question here and I've searched and searched (for two days so far) to no avail. I am trying to scrape a particular retail website to get the product name and the price.

Currently, I have one spider working on one particular retail website however, with another retail website, it sort of works. I can get the product name correctly, but I cannot get the price in the right format.

Firstly, this is my spider code currently:

```
import scrapy

from projectname.items import projectItem

class spider_whatever(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "whatever"
    allowed_domain = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.domain.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = scrapy.Selector(response)
        requests = sel.xpath('//div@class="container"]')
        product = requests.xpath('.//*[@class="productname"/text()]').extract()
        price = requests.xpath('.//*[@class="price"]').extract() #Issue lies here.

        itemlist = []
        for product, price in zip(product, price):
            item = projectItem()
            item['product'] = product.strip().upper()
            item['price'] = price.strip()
            itemlist.append(item)
        return itemlist
```

Now the target HTML for the price  is:

```
<div id="listPrice1" class="price">
                        $622                        <div class="cents">.00</div>
                    </div>
```

As you can see, not only is it messy, it has a div within the div I want to reference. Now when I go and try and do this:

```
price = requests.xpath('.//*[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
```

It spits out this:

```
product,price
some_product1, $100
some_product2, 
some_product3, $200
some_product4,
```

When it is supposed to spit out:

```
product,price
some_product1, $100
some_product2, $200
some_product3, $300
some_product4, $400
```

What I think it is doing is; it is also extracting div class="cents" and assigning that to the next product therefore pushing the next value down one.

When I try and scrape the data via Google Docs Spreadsheet, it puts the product in one column, and the price is split into two columns; the first being the $amount and the second being the .00 cents as shown below:

```
product,price,cents
some_product1, $100, .00
some_product2, $200, .00
some_product3, $300, .00
some_product4, $400, .00
```

So my question is, how do I separate the div in a div. Is there a particular way of excluding it from the XPath or can I filter it out when I parse the data? And if I can filter it out, how would I do this?

Any help is much appreciated. Please understand, I am relatively new to Python and am trying my best to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's explore a few different XPath patterns:

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""<div id="listPrice1" class="price">
...                         $622                        <div class="cents">.00</div>
...                     </div>""")

# /text() will select all text nodes under the context not,
# here any element with class "price"
# there are 2 of them
>>> selector.xpath('.//*[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
[u'\n                        $622                        ', u'\n                    ']

# if you wrap the context node inside the "string()" function,
# you'll get the string representation of the node,
# basically a concatenation of text elements
>>> selector.xpath('string(.//*[@class="price"])').extract()
[u'\n                        $622                        .00\n                    ']

# using "normalize-space()" instead of "string()",
# it will replace multiple space with 1 space character
>>> selector.xpath('normalize-space(.//*[@class="price"])').extract()
[u'$622 .00']

# you could also ask for the 1st text node under the element with class "price"
>>> selector.xpath('.//*[@class="price"]/text()[1]').extract()
[u'\n                        $622                        ']

# space-normalized version of that may do what you want
>>> selector.xpath('normalize-space(.//*[@class="price"]/text()[1])').extract()
[u'$622']
>>>
```

So, in the end, you may be after this pattern:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = scrapy.Selector(response)
    requests = sel.xpath('//div@class="container"]')
    itemlist = []
    for r in requests:
        item = projectItem()
        item['product'] = r.xpath('normalize-space(.//*[@class="productname"])').extract()
        item['price'] = r.xpath('normalize-space(.//*[@class="price"]/text()[1])').extract()
        itemlist.append(item)
    return itemlist
```

Comment: You are an absolute champion! I didn't know you could select specific text nodes! That is great! Thank you!